# Converting int to binary in C / Arduino

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

I'm having a really hard time trying to convert an INT to an 8 bit Binary number.

There's plenty of code on how to do this online however most of them need libraries in order to work, and Arduino doesn't support libraries from C as it has its own.

If anyone has any idea on how to go about doing this without using C libraries, maybe just using some loops, it would be much appreciated

For example:

if the input is 5
the output should be 00000101

Thanks

Comment: Two critical parts are missing from this question - what code did you try, and how did it fail.

Comment: "none of them seem to work" means next to nothing, and less than that when there is nothing to relate it to.

Comment: Can you add an example of input and output expected ? Do you want to display 4 as 0100 ?

Comment: An integer *is* a binary value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the binary value of an integer using the bitwise.

As far as I am concerned, I'm using this kind of function to understand how it works :

```
int     main()
{
  int   nb = 10;
  int   i = 31;

  while (i >= 0) {
    if ((nb >> i) & 1)
      printf("1");
    else
      printf("0");
    --i;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

In this code, the **i** represents the selected bit. With this selected bit, I'm searching if it's a 1 using the logical AND (&) operator. If it is, I print "1" and I select the next bit until the end of the number (which contains 32 bits, because it's an integer).

There is many way to obtain the value using the bitwise.. You have to try it yourself to understand better !

Good luck!

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answer, I've tried to implement this into Arduino however I'm a bit confused as to what the input value of your code is? It doesn't print anything at the moment for me

Comment: In fact, with this code, I'm trying to get the binary value of the integer **nb** (which is 10 in this example). The output is actually `00000000000000000000000000001010` because I print all the bit that **nb** contains.

Comment: I kind of got it working now, however because the values are printed directly, I have no way of capturing the result. Would you know how to store the result within a String or INT?

Comment: If you want to store the printed value, you've to use a string variable.. I don't think that there is an over way to store that big value. Anyway, why do you want to store the binary value ? What do you want to do ? Because the value is already stored in the integer variable!

Comment: @MikeSmithMusic You'll want to use an array of ints.

Comment: Even better if you just write a simple function to get a specific bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro to get a specific bit of a number:

```
#define BIT(n,i) (n>>i&1)
```

Usage is as follows:

```
BIT(10,0) //Gets bit 0 of int 10.
```

Answer (score 0):

> Integer converted to an Array containing the Binary equivalent.

> I wrote this for my personal use because I didn't want to use a library.
>
> Some examples:

> If testInterger is 255 then Output is 11111111.
>
> If testInterger is a 0 then Output is 00000000.
>
> If testInterger is 127 then Output is 01111111.
>
> If testInterger is 100 then Output is 01100100.

```
char newArray[8]="00000000"; // Make an Array to hold the 8 Bits.
int arrayPosition=0;         // Keep track of the position of each Bit.
int testInteger=100;         // Any number from 0-255.

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);

  for(int a=128; a>=1; a=a/2){      // This loop will start at 128, then 64, then 32, etc.
    if((testInteger-a)>=0){         // This checks if the Int is big enough for the Bit to be a '1'
      newArray[arrayPosition]='1';  // Assigns a '1' into that Array position.
      testInteger-=a;}              // Subracts from the Int.
    else{
      newArray[arrayPosition]='0';} // The Int was not big enough, therefore the Bit is a '0'
      arrayPosition++;                // Move one Character to the right in the Array.
    }

  Serial.println(newArray);

// OR if you want to print it one character at a time with spaces between
//    just to see that it is an Array...
//      for(int a=0; a<=7; a++){
//        Serial.print(newArray[a]);
//        Serial.print(" ");
//      }

}

void loop(){  
}
```

I don't know what your time constraints are, but this takes .016 milliseconds to run. Or 16 microseconds.

I use this for streaming Voice/Music/SoundFx data from an W25QXX 8-Meg Serial Flash IC for a game I built. 8 Megs allows for over 16 minutes of sound using 8000hz sample. So the .016 Milliseconds was negligible for me.